# Cypress.io - timeout when typing from wrap

Tags: cypress

I'm new to Cypress and Javascript.

I have a wrapped JSON object and set an alias for it in the beforeEach function.
I'm trying to set input field with a property in the JSON object.

```html
beforeEach(function () {
    cy.wrap({username:"richard@cypresstest.com"}).as('userLoginWrap');
  })

it.only('should log user in successfully', function () {

  cy.get('@userLoginWrap').its('username').should('eq', 'richard@cypresstest.com'); // Passed
  
  cy.get('#usernameField')
      .type(cy.get('@userLoginWrap').its('username')); // Error: Cypress command timeout of '4000ms' exceeded.
})
```

How can i get around this?

Thank you.

Comment: What's going wrong here? Is there an error, and if so can you post the error message you're getting?

Comment: Hey Joshua, i'm actually getting Error: Cypress command timeout of '4000ms' exceeded.for the last line of code in Cypress GUI. cheers

Answer (score 0):

`cy.type( text )` takes string. You're passing it a cy command, which isn't synchronous.

You could do something crazy like this (untested):

```
beforeEach(function () {
  cy.wrap({username:"richard@cypresstest.com"}).as('userLoginWrap');
})

it.only('should log user in successfully', function () {
  let username;
  cy.get('@userLoginWrap').its('username').should('eq', 'richard@cypresstest.com')
    .then( obj => username = obj.username );

  cy.get('#usernameField')
      .type( username );
})
```

But I'd prefer storing the `"richard@cypresstest.com"` to a constant --- that way you won't have to repeat it like you're doing right now, plus avoid the shenanigans with storing to variables using `.then()` commands.

Alternatively, use [fixtures](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Requirements).